# Dealing with ethereum LOG1-2-3-4 opcodes: How to parse them correctly?

Tags: events, transaction-trace

I'm trying to do some analysis of events from the opcodes of transactions, but I'm finding it very hard to understand how can I find the index_topics and the values returned by the event. For instance:

```
{
  pc: 1243,
  op: 'LOG2',
  gas: 95970,
  gasCost: 1381,
  depth: 2,
  stack: [
    '0xd0e30db0',
    '0x3d2',
    '0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d',
    '0xe1fffcc4923d04b559f4d29a8bfc6cda04eb5b0d3c460751c2402c5c5cc9109c',
    '0x20',
    '0x60'
  ],
  memory: [
    '0000000000000000000000007a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060',
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000'
  ]
}
```

In this log, the address `0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d` (index_topic_1) deposits 1 Eth (`0xde0b6b3a7640000`) (data returned by the event) into WEth. The index_topic_0 is `0xe1fffcc4923d04b559f4d29a8bfc6cda04eb5b0d3c460751c2402c5c5cc9109c`. So I can see that all the data that I need (except the address of the contract firing the event) is there, I'm just not sure if it's always in this order and I can trust it.

In other events I do find the returned data that I need in both the stack and in the memory, but I don't know how to confidently parse it from the memory.

Some questions I have:

- What are the memory objects `3` and `60` in positions 1 and 2?
- How can I find the address that fired this event? The only way I can think of is looking for the most recent `CALL`, `STATICCALL`, `DELEGATECALL` or `CALLCODE` and look for the `to` parameter, but it sounds like a hassle
- How can I interpret the rest of the things on the stack? I see that the `index topics` are there, but in positions that don't make any sense to me (index_topic_1 in stack index = 2 and index_topic_0 in stack index = 3, and I have no idea what are the other 4 items in the stack, not sure if they are even related to the event log)

I would appreciate any type of information that you could give me about parsing this event opcodes, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Yellow paper documentation of the LOG opcodes the format is:

- stack[0] pointer memory
- stack[1] size memory
- stack[2] first topic
- stack[3] second topic & so on

From your capture the stack is reversed

```
  stack: [
    '0xd0e30db0',
    '0x3d2',
    '0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d',
    '0xe1fffcc4923d04b559f4d29a8bfc6cda04eb5b0d3c460751c2402c5c5cc9109c',
    '0x20',
    '0x60'
  ],
```

- 0x60 points to `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000`
- 0x20 length = 32 bytes
- first topic  `0xe1fffcc4923d04b559f4d29a8bfc6cda04eb5b0d3c460751c2402c5c5cc9109c`
- second topic `0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d` (it will be padded to 32 bytes

---

If I'm not wrong memory 0x0-0x3f are scratch memory used by some solidity operations.

Memory at 0x40-0x5f is a pointer to free memory. In this case free memory starts at 0x60.

Also in newer solc versions memory address at 0x60-0x7f is zeroed on purpose, and the free memory starts at 0x80.

---

I think you are correct that accessing current contract you have to track those opcodes.

Comment: Very very enlightening, thanks!

Comment: @Hiperfly were you able to implement this? Particularly keeping track of the last `CALL` and other similar opcodes?